# How to show and hide text in CSS according to it's length with transition

Tags: css, angularjs

In this example, I'm using "angular animate" transition to show and hide the text, but I want to the show and hide option be according to text length.

[image]

```
<div class="toggle">
<h3 style="display:inline-block;">CSS toggle feature</h3>
<div class="button" style="display:inline-block;">
<input ng-click="example1=!example1"  type="checkbox" value="selected" id="someID1" class="toggle__input">
<label for="someID1" class="toggle__label">Show <span class="toggle__more"> More</span>
<span class="toggle__less">Less</span>
</label>
</div>
<div ng-show="example1" class="cssSlideUp ng-scope ng-animate" style="">
<div class="toggle__content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis sequi quidem officia quis, repellendus voluptas voluptatibus in adipisci magnam consectetur, reprehenderit laborum ducimus ipsum dolores dicta vero. Laudantium inventore, reprehenderit!</p>
</div>
</div>
```

`.cssSlideUp {
    transition: .5s linear all;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

That page has a Plunker at the bottom for an example.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
   <input id="setbtn" type="button" value="set" ng-click="myVar='my-class'">
   <input id="clearbtn" type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
   <br>
   <span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</span>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.base-class {
   transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}

.base-class.my-class {
   color: red;
   font-size:3em;
}
```